# See file access records if not super user

Tags: linux, files

Is it possible to see who has accessed a file (not necessarily modified) if you don't have admin rights on linux?

For e.g.,

user `A` has permission `rwxr--r--` on a folder `B` and user `C` reads a file `D` from folder `B`. Will it be possible for `A` to see that `C` accessed `D`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, even for root, Linux doesn't do that level of auditing out of the box. You have to install and configure [auditd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) for your distro to see those events.

User A would also need to have permission to read the log files so the real answer is likely to be no.